# PyQt: multiple labels on same line

Tags: layout, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a simple layout component where I have a text followed by counter. Ideally it would look like the first example in following picture but instead it looks like second example:

[image]

Numbers are variables which depends on user selections or progress, thus I have own variables for those in my code and whole line is built of four distinct QLabel widgets: one for text, one for each counter and one for slash. But for some reason those labels takes a lot of space, I've set the background color of first label to red to illustrate the problem.

How I should implement this so that I get the result of first example but I can individually control those counters? I've tried to change margins, size policy etc. but nothing seems to work correctly.

Here is current implementation:

```
    progress_line = QHBoxLayout()
    label = QLabel('Example label:')
    progress_line.addWidget(label)
    progress_line.addWidget(self.progress_count_current)
    progress_line.addWidget(QLabel('/'))
    progress_line.addWidget(self.progress_count_total)

    # Add to other layout
    parent.addLayout(progress_line)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see what is the problem in your code since you didn't show all of it, I don't know what kind of object is "self.progress_count_current" and "self.progress_count_total". But I have this small example that seems to do what you need. Have a try and see if it works.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget


class Widget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()

        self.h_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.h_layout)

        self.label = QLabel('Example label:')
        self.current_value = '1'
        self.total_value = '3'

        self.label_current = QLabel(self.current_value)
        self.slash_label = QLabel('/')
        self.label_total = QLabel(self.total_value)

        self.h_layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.h_layout.addWidget(self.label_current)
        self.h_layout.addWidget(self.slash_label)
        self.h_layout.addWidget(self.label_total)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = Widget()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```